# Working with hierarchyid in Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, hierarchyid

I'm working with EF Core 3.1 and i use sql server datatype **hierarchyid** on one of my tables.

When i scaffold the table into my project the 'hierarchyid' turns into Geometry type.

I tried manually changing into SqlHierarchyId type with the help of  dotMorten.Microsoft.SqlServer.Types package.

Code in my API :

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("")]
public ActionResult<List<EntityDto>> Get()
{
   EntityRepository repo = new EntityRepository (_context);
   var reults = repo.GetAll().ToList(); // <-- fails here
   return _mapper.Map<List<Entity>, List<EntityDto>>(reults);
}
```

GetAll() returns this :

```
protected DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
{
   return dbSet;
}
```

But when I try to get the list of this entities i get an error :

```
Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlHierarchyId' to type 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.Server.IBinarySerialize'.
```

I didn't find any way to overcome this error.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Maybe you can use this package? https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.HierarchyId

Comment: I can't believe i never saw this package, i was searching for so long, it works like a charm, Thank you so much !